# Using Recursion to Calculate (n + r)!/(n! * r!)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int func(int n, int r);
int main(){
    int n,r;
    int result=0;
    printf("Enter the number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the 2.number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&r);

   result=func(n,r);
   printf("%d",result);

    return(0);
}
int func(int n, int r){
    if(r==1){
        return(n);
    }
   if(n>0 && r>0){
       return ((n+r) / (n*r))* func(n-1,r-1);
   }
}
```

I wrote code but it does not work. I entered n=5 and r=2, result is 0. And I want to calculate this recursively. I want to calculate (n+r)!/(n!*r!)

Answer (score 3):

The formula for combinations (n+r)! / (n! * r!) can be written as

```
( 1 * 2 * 3 ... * n+r ) / (( 1 * 2 * 3 ... * n ) * ( 1 * 2 * 3 ... * r ))
```

Canceling out common terms this is:

```
( n+1 * n+2 ... * n+r ) / ( 1 * 2 * 3 ... * r)
```

This suggests a simple loop from 1 to r.  At each step the upper product will be divisible by the next lower term, for example  any two consecutive numbers are divisible by 2, any three by 3, etc.

Example n=100, r=5

```
1 * 101 / 1
101 * 102 / 2
5151 * 103 / 3
176851 * 104 / 4
4598126 * 105 / 5
= 96560646
```

Comment: nice... I was trying... but: rusty math, well done.

Comment: Yes.  Your recursive approach will work and be simpler which I'll leave to you to figure out.

Comment: I do not use loop

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `int`s.

Try `double` instead.

---

To elaborate:

This part: `(n+r) / (n*r)`, will be 7 / 10, for n=5 and r=2.

The result will be put in an `int`, but `int` does not allow fractions and will be `floored`, and hence, will be `0`

---

If your requirement is to use recursion and int's, you need to rewrite the algorithm. Although, I wonder how a fraction would make sense to be represented as an int.

You could split the calculation for (n+r)! and (n!*r!), they will be easily handled with your algorithm (careful, might cause overflow rapidly), and divide later.

---

Anyhow, by doing some math, it will get easier, there might be a way to simplify the problem.

Comment: I have to use int function and recursive :/

Comment: Then you must change the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `int` and recursion, you need to design a better algorithm.
Firstly notice that `A=(n+r)!/n!` will be equal to `(n+r)(n+r-1)...(n+1)`.
Then it is also possible to proof that $A/r!$ is some integer.

So one idea is firstly use recursion to compute `A`, and then use recursion to compute `B=r!`.

The code looks like this: (assuming n is global)

```
long long computeA(int currentn){
    if (currentn==n+1){
        return n+1;
    }
    return currentn*computeA(currentn-1);
}

long long computeB(int currentr){
    if (currentr==1){
        return 1;
    }
    return currentr*computeB(currentr-1);
}

int main(){
    /* whatever */
    long long A;
    A=computeA(n+r);
    long long B;
    B=computeB(r);
    printf("%lld",A/B);
    /* whatever */
}
```

Do notice that `a!` get very large for approximately `a>20`. Be careful.

Comment: @anonim Then maybe follow stark's approach, but change the loop to recursion.